# c# Асинхронный вызов метода

Tags: c#, многопоточность, методы, асинхронность

У меня существует метод, который возвращает список:

```
public static List<string> GetWord(string getWord, int length)
{
   
   List<string> keysWordFinal = new List<string>();
   //код
   return keysWordFinal; //возвращаем этот лист
}
```

Так же, существует код, который вызывает этот метод при нажатии на кнопку:

```
private void hackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GetText = TextBox.Text;
   TextBox.Text = temptext;
   List<string> keysFinal = new List<string>(); //лист, в который сохраняется
   keysFinal = HackClass.GetWord(GetText, length); //вызов метода с заданными параметрами
}
```

Необходимо вызвать методов GetWord асинхронно (или как-то с помощью потоков), т.к. программа при работе данного метода намертво зависает.

Пробовал вот так сделать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как ещё можно попробовать реализовать это?

Comment: Расскажите подробнее про метод GetWord: он выполняет тяжёлые процессорные вычисления? И откуда вы его вызываете - это какое-то WPF приложение? Если оба раза ответ "да", то не нужно выполнять тяжёлые вычисления в GUI потоке (в основном потоке), об этом тут очень много уже готовых ответов.

Comment: GetWord - метод в публичном классе (HackClass). Да, там довольно-таки сложные вычисления, из-за которых программа виснет на минуту или две (ищутся пары ключей)

Comment: Я пытался реализовать варианты, которые предлагают (выше приложил скриншоты). Так же, пытался запустить вот так: https://pastenow.ru/C5FN7

Comment: `keysFinal = new List<string>()` - здесь вы создали экземпляр списка. И тут же его потеряли в следующей строке: `keysFinal = HackClass.GetWord`. Вы уже не новичок, а такие элементарные ошибки делаете.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо огромное за указание на ошибку. Исправил. Скорее всего, по невнимательности написал дважды

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetWord` оставляем без изменений.

```cs
private async void hackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GetText = TextBox.Text;
   TextBox.Text = temptext;
   try
   {
       List<string> keysFinal = await Task.Run(() => HackClass.GetWord(GetText, length));
       MessageBox.Show("Готово!");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

[Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Обратите внимание, `try-catch` я добавил не случайно. Это нужно для того, чтобы если у вас возникнет исключение, вы смогли его увидеть. В `async void` методах исключения не останавливают выполнение кода основного потока, так как он не ожидает завершения параллельных вычислений. Следовательно, если убрать здесь обработку исключений, то вместо исключения не будет показываться ничего. У вас не будет получаться ожидаемый результат, и вы не увидите причину. Поэтому обязательно обрабатывайте все исключения, если метод `async void` в обязательном порядке.

Comment: Спасибо огромное - это помогло. Метод GetWord очень большой (около 250 строк), поэтому не думаю, что нужно. Огромное спасибо, ещё раз :)

Comment: @Frehzy ну задайте отдельный вопрос. Если метод рабочий, и вы просто хотите попробовать его ускорить или оптимизировать код, задайте вопрос с меткой `инспекция-кода`, разберем ошибки, придумаем как ускорить. Только если у него есть методы, которые он вызывает для работы, их код тоже покажите тогда.

Comment: Ещё такой вопрос: У меня есть в этом методе цикл, который я хотел-бы, чтобы его прогресс отображался в progressBar, который находится в форме. Чисто теоретически, можно как-нибудь так это реализовать? (length - максимальное число в цикле for, maxLength - число, которое в данный момент прокручивается в цикле) https://pastenow.ru/C5G5N

Comment: @Frehzy очень просто: создайте в начале `hackButton_Click` экземпляр `IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(v => metroProgressBar1.Value = v);` Передайте `progress` как аргумент в метод `GetWord`, внутри метода вызывайте `progress.Report(time);`. Никаких форм создавать не нужно, и работать с интерфейсом напрямую из стороннего потока не получится.