# Timer и progressBar C#

Tags: c#, winforms, таймер

Мне нужно сделать таймер на 25 минут, который по истечению времени закрывает форму. При этом должен быть progressBar который отображает эти 25 минут.
Пробую так:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Maximum = 25 * 60 * 1000;
            Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
            MyTimer.Interval = (25 * 60 * 1000); // 25 mins
            MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
            MyTimer.Start();
        }

        private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            if (count <= 25 * 60 * 1000)
                progressBar1.Value = count;
            MessageBox.Show("The form will now be closed.", "Time Elapsed");
            this.Close();
        }
```

Но по результату этого кода progressBar ничего не отображает. В чём ошибка? И можно ли progressBar установить вертикально?

Comment: У вас интервал таймера 25 минут, то есть 1 вызов за 25 минут

Comment: @tym32167 А сколько поставить?

Comment: Ну а как часто вам надо обновлять ваш прогресс бар?

Comment: @tym32167 Ну вот сейчас ставил 100 милисекунд и всё равно ничего не показывал

Comment: `progressBar1.Maximum` поменьше поставьте. 100мс ваш `count` будет 10 через секунду, сколько процентов это от `25 * 60 * 1000`?

Comment: @aepot Насколько меньше? На 100 поставил и ничего

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример без таймеров. Также важно отметить, что тут время не завсит от количества вызовов, оно зависит только от времени. При желаении, можно его ещё чуть улучить и сделать точнее

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        this.Width = 500;
        this.Height = 500;
        var button = new Button() { Text = "Close me in 20 secs", Width = 200, Height = 50 };
        var pg = new ProgressBar() { Maximum = 100, Width = 200, Height = 50, Top = 50 };

        this.Controls.Add(button);
        this.Controls.Add(pg);

        button.Click += async (sender, args) =>
        {   
            var startTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var endTimeUtc = startTimeUtc.AddSeconds(20);

            var duration = endTimeUtc - startTimeUtc;

            while (endTimeUtc > DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000); // refresh rate 

                var remaining = endTimeUtc - DateTime.UtcNow;
                int progress = (int)(100.0 - 100.0 * remaining.TotalSeconds / duration.TotalSeconds);

                pg.Value = progress;
            }

            this.Close();
        };
    }
}
```

[image: ...]

Добавляйте по вкусу опции и прчие вещи, вплоть до отмены операции.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю такой варинат:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Shown += Form1_Shown;
        }

        private async void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            progressBar1.Value = 100;
            for (int i = 25 * 60; i > 0; i--) {
                progressBar1.Value = i * 100 / (25 * 60);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
            Close();
        }
    }
```

Без таймера. С асинк-авэйтами. Очень коротенечко :-)

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает! А не подскажете ещё, как реализовать тоже самое, только так: у меня есть три радио-кнопки с 25,20,15 минут, как от их выбора сделать соотвевствующий таймер?

Comment: `Task.Delay` дает задержку больше, чем указано. За счет расходов на асинхронность. Нужно корректировать ожидание по часам. Соврет примерно на несколько минут в большую сторону.

Comment: @aepot - Согласен, нужно скрестить мой пример с работой с TimeSpan из примера tym32767

Comment: @S.H. [Пример, как откорректировать погрешность Task.Delay](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1265190/373567). Если этот метод [скрестить с токеном отмены](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257322/373567), получится четкая красивая реализация с возможностью остановки. А то что вы предложили, если форму закрыть раньше времени, через 25 минут оно упадет с исключением при попытке закрыть уже закрытую форму.

Comment: ...Так как исключения в `async void` вы [не ловите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1268031/373567), автор конечно его не увидит, но оно будет с вероятностью 100%, если конечно приложение не будет полностью закрыто раньше.